# Javascript post form

Tags: javascript, forms

Im trying to submit a form by javascript, after a specific field is validated.

im using

```
function doValidate(){
        var error = false;
        var nr = document.getElementById('number').value;
    if (nr > '10'){
        document.getElementById('number').className += " red";
        error = true;
    }
    if (error = false) {
        document.forms["new_qs"].submit();
    }
}
```

but when error is false, just nothing happens!
I inspected the site with firebug, error is false, the `document.forms` seems to do nothing. 
But in Online Tutorials this is working very good.

Here is a complete fiddle from the site http://jsfiddle.net/S7G9J/25/

What could be the problem/solution?

Comment: You could also just use `if (!error)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (error = false) {
```

In the above, you are using assignment operator. `=`. Use `==` to compare

Also you are comparing string instead of numbers.

Try this:

```
function doValidate(){
    var error = false;
    var nr = Number(document.getElementById('number').value);
    if (nr > 10){
        document.getElementById('number').className += " red";
        error = true;
    }
    if (error === false) {
        document.querySelector('[type="button"]').submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: @HKK: You have to compare numbers, not strings. Use `>= 10`. And then of course there is no form with name `new_qs` in your jsFiddle.

Comment: @HKK: `TypeError: document.forms.new_qs is undefined` [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: Ah. Thank You, so it was maybe just the `==` in the end?

Comment: @HKK: No, the problems have been `error = false`, `> '10'` and `document.forms["new_qs"]`. All things could have found by yourself by doing some basic debugging on your own. I recommend to read link I posted in previous comment, so that you don't have to rely on others to solve these kinds of problems (because they can happen a lot and waiting for others just slows you down).

Comment: The `Number` call is actually not necessary since `>` converts the operand to a number anyway. But it might make the intend clearer :)

Comment: @FelixKling yeah! Forgot implicit conversion!

Comment: thank you, I will take a look at it. but the `document.forms["new_qs"] only came from copying to fiddle. in my orginal code this ID exists. but it didn't worked. so it has to be the `==` and the `>'10'`

Comment: @HKK: OK, but how are we supposed to know which errors you really have and which ones you introduced by creating an example? It's your responsibility to make sure to not add new errors when creating the example.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies in the line where you submit() the form.

In your fiddle, your form's id is "test". In your javascript, the form you're referencing should have an id of "new_qs". However, there is no such form, so there is no submit() processed.

document.forms[0].submit() will submit the first form in order of appearance in your HTML. So, try this:

```
function doValidate(){
    var error = false;
    var nr = document.getElementById('number').value;
if (nr > '10'){
    document.getElementById('number').className += " red";
    error = true;
}
if (error == false) { // need double equal here
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
}
```